# On Click Toggles Submenu

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, onclick, submenu

I've done quite a bit of searching, but haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to achieve an effect to where when the Parent menu item is clicked, a div containing a submenu with links relative to that parent item is dropped down and displayed.  I've created an example here to give an idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/WeL6j/1/

However, I don't want the grey div - #9e9e9e '#div' - to be covered.  I understand the reason for this is because I've set the content position to fixed, however if I take off the position attribute, the submenus show up below their respective parent; opposed to being positioned all the way to the left.

Thanks in advance for any help, Bc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is http://jsfiddle.net/WeL6j/7/ what you wanted to do? If so, I think it is easiest to place the hidden divs below the nav bar, where they should be displayed. Then just hide/display as neccessary

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  I just needed a basic version to adapt to the design I have in mind.

Comment: So, one more question regarding this.  It's working perfectly in the jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/WeL6j/10/ ), however when I try to load it into my templates code - which is very basic at the moment as I'm just starting it - it won't reveal the hidden div.  I noticed in fiddle that when I change the javascript panel to Javascript 1.7 it won't reveal anymore.  I'm wondering if that's what my template is using and if so, how do I make the fiddle version compatible with it?  Thanks in advance, Brian.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try toggle, a jQuery method:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I'm very new to jquery, but I think I was using the toggle function correctly in the above fiddle.  Michael, below, provided me with the answer I was searching for, but thank you for the reply and help.  Once my reputation is high enough, I'll be sure to come back and one up your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're looking for a a functionality similar to jQuery tabs. Check collapsible option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#collapsible

You'll have to extend it a bit so that content slides down instead of showing up: example:

http://jsfiddle.net/s6m7E/4/

Comment: Is there anyway you could apply it to the fiddle that I posted above?  My knowledge of jquery is very beginner and I've found one that works the way I like, except that it's stacked vertically (like yours).  I'm hoping to get it in a horizontal format, so that I can use it for a navigation menu.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  Michael, above, achieved exactly what I was going for.  Once I reach a rep of 15+, I'll be sure to come back and one up your response for the help.